# ms dynamics crm. Assign invokes Update message plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, assign

I have a plugin PostEntityUpdate which have to be invoked after updating an entity. But this plugin is invoked even if I just assign my entity record to another user. How can avoid invoking this plugin when I assign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check in update plugin which message origin that call. Like that:

```cs
IPluginExecutionContext pContext = context.ParentContext;
if(pContext.MessageName == "Assign") return;
```